# javascript-dropdown option remove

Tags: javascript

I have three dropdowns

```
First dropdown options are

option1
option2


2nd and third dropdowns are

optionA
OptionB
```

When I select option2 in first dropdown

I should remove optionA from both dropdowns.

When I select option1, my both dropdowns should repopulate with original values.

I am using the following code to remove from one dropdown only

Can anybody point me how to do two dropdowns at same time please.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
google.load("jquery", "1.4.2");
google.setOnLoadCallback(function() 
{
    var sites='#firstDDId';
    $('#firstDDId').change(function() 
            {
                if($(sites).val()=='Option1' ) 
                {
                        alert(" Please note, optionA will be removed"); 
                         $("#secondDDId option[value='OptionA']").remove(); 
                                         } 
               else
                {
                  var exists = false;
                  $('#SecondDDId option').each(function()
                  {
                        if (this.value == 'OptionA') 
                        {

                            exists = true;

                            return false;
                        }
                    }
                );

                    if (exists==false)
                    {
                        $("#SecondDDId").append('<option value="OptionA">OptionA</option>');
                    }

                 }  
        });



  });

</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Store your options first in an array and then you can repopulate your select options every time you need.

Answer (score 0):

Change $("#secondDDId option[value='OptionA']").remove();
into $("option[value='OptionA']").remove();

This will remove all the options with value OptionA.

if ($("#SecondDDId option[value='OptionA']").length == 0)
     $("#SecondDDId").append('OptionA');

This will re-add the option.

To target the second and third drop down at the same time, you could use $("select[id$='DDId'] option[value='OptionA']").

Answer (score 0):

You were on the right track there. You were just missing the dynamic part. I changed some variables and id's for better readability too.

```
<!doctype html>
<head>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<select id="control-ddl">
    <option value="1">1</option>
    <option value="2">2</option>
</select>
<select id="child-ddl-1">
    <option value="A">A</option>
    <option value="B">B</option>
    <option value="C">C</option>
</select>
<select id ="child-ddl-2">
    <option value="A">A</option>
    <option value="B">B</option>
    <option value="C">C</option>
</select> 
<select id ="child-ddl-3">
    <option value="A">A</option>
    <option value="B">B</option>
    <option value="C">C</option>
</select> 
<select id ="child-ddl-4">
    <option value="A">A</option>
    <option value="B">B</option>
    <option value="C">C</option>
</select> 
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $("#control-ddl").change(function() {
            // Array of child select id's; only these get the "A" option
            // stripped and readded when control-ddl changes
            var ddlIds = [ "#child-ddl-1", "#child-ddl-2", "#child-ddl-3" ];
            $.each(ddlIds, function(idx, ddlId) {
                if($("#control-ddl").val()=="2") {
                    $(ddlId + " option[value='A']").remove();
                }   else {
                    var exists = false;
                    $(ddlId + " > option").each(function() {
                        if (this.value == "A") { 
                            exists = true;
                            return;
                        }
                    });
                    if (!exists) {
                        $(ddlId).append("<option value='A'>A</option>");
                    }
                }
            });  
        });
    });
</script>
</body>
</html>
```